# jQuery v1.11.3 sending me controls.png 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the Inspect Element console section I am getting this error:

GET http://.../img/controls.png 404 (Not Found)  jquery-1.11.3.js:10208

Extra:

> (anonymous function)  @   jquery-1.11.3.js:10208
>   jQuery.access @   jquery-1.11.3.js:4182 jQuery.each.jQuery.fn.(anonymous
>   function) @   jquery-1.11.3.js:10204
>   shareSwitch   @   valnet.social.js?v=2.0:170 (anonymous
>   function) @   include.js?v=2.0:40 m.Callbacks.j   @   jquery.js?ver=1.11.2:2
>   m.Callbacks.k.fireWith    @   jquery.js?ver=1.11.2:2
>   m.extend.ready    @   jquery.js?ver=1.11.2:2 J    @   jquery.js?ver=1.11.2:2

When I click on the error it sends me here:

```
// Create scrollLeft and scrollTop methods
jQuery.each( { scrollLeft: "pageXOffset", scrollTop: "pageYOffset" }, function( method, prop ) {
    var top = /Y/.test( prop );

    jQuery.fn[ method ] = function( val ) {
        return access( this, function( elem, method, val ) {
            var win = getWindow( elem );

            if ( val === undefined ) {
                return win ? (prop in win) ? win[ prop ] :
                    win.document.documentElement[ method ] :
                    elem[ method ];
            }

            if ( win ) {
                win.scrollTo(
                    !top ? val : jQuery( win ).scrollLeft(),
                    top ? val : jQuery( win ).scrollTop()
                );

            } else {
                elem[ method ] = val;
            }
        }, method, val, arguments.length, null );
    };
});
```

It highlights this line:

```
return win ? (prop in win) ? win[ prop ] :
```

I just can't figure out what the problem is. Is there a way to track the source of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a CSS property background-image trying to get an image that did not exists. Strangely enough Google Chrome saw it as an JS error.

I only had to remove the background-image.

Comment: I had the same issue, I had to find and remove controls.png from a random CSS page.

Comment: What is the solution , I did not understand your comment , thanks in advance